# pay collateral with cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, collateral, preprod

Followed the guide [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/create-stake-pool-keys/#payment-key-pair) to build preprod testnet wallets, was wondering however I can create the collateral utxo with `cardano-cli` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly some of the developers.cardano.org documentation is outdated.

You need to use `--tx-in-collateral` to specify your collateral input, but might want to also use the `--tx-out-return-collateral` flag to specify your output.

Comment: Oh no I think my question is wrong - is there a way to even create the collateral input?

Comment: There is nothing specific about a collateral input, you can use any input.

In the past, this has been problematic as we did not have output return collateral, so the whole utxo was spend, therefore wallets introduced a term of collateral input setup to limit potential lost.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using web wallets e.g. Eternl to create the collateral utxo. And used `cardano-address` and `cardano-cli` to create payment and stake `.skey` files.